# How do I capitalize text in breadcrumbs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the html containing bootstrap's `breadcrumb`,

```css
.breadcrumb {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 8px 15px 0 35px;
}

.breadcrumb>li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.breadcrumb>li+li:before {
  content: "\3E";
  color: #b1afaf;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">MEP SERVICES </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lighting</a></li>
  <li>HT &amp; LT</li>
</ul>
```

Now its look and feel is,

[image]

I want below look and feel.

[image]

I have tried below `css` , but not working.

```css
.breadcrumb>li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use   `text-transform: capitalize;` in `a`

```css
.breadcrumb {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 8px 15px 0 35px;
}

.breadcrumb>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.breadcrumb>li+li:before {
  content: "\3E";
  color: #b1afaf;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.breadcrumb>li>a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">mep services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">electrical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">lighting</a></li>
  <li>HT &amp; LT</li>
</ul>
```

if you really want to have `MEP SERVICES` fully capitalized in html then you need a bit more code for that:

```css
.breadcrumb {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 8px 15px 0 35px;
}

.breadcrumb>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.breadcrumb>li+li:before {
  content: "\3E";
  color: #b1afaf;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.breadcrumb>li>a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.breadcrumb>li:first-of-type>a {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.breadcrumb>li:first-of-type>a:first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
 /* for ::first-letter work `a` needs to be block level element */
.breadcrumb>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">MEP SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">electrical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">lighting</a></li>
  <li>HT &amp; LT</li>
</ul>
```